# Access VM Console through Smart Phone

Tags: kvm-virtualization, android, ovirt

Hey guys I need some little help. I have a KVM and used oVirt for the management of VMs. What I want is that my client will log on to their account and access their virtual machine using their Smart phone. I tried to install mOvirt and yes can connect to the console of my machine, but it is only accesible for admin console. Tried to use web console, it downloaded console.vv but can't open it. By any chance could make this thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

mOvirt seems like the mobile version of the admin portal, so no wonder you only get the admin console.

The .vv file you download is metadata for `virt-viewer` (aka remote-viewer) and nothing else. I am not aware of an android app that is capable of using it directly, but with a bit of work you might be able to get one of the available Spice client (aSpice, flexVDI etc) working.

Generally speaking, the oVirt VDI feature set is very much Windows and Linux client oriented.

Comment: Hi dyasny, you mean to say that it is not possible to acquire the console of the machine as a user? I have tried to configure out the aSpice for direct connection but it didn't works. Do you have other method for this? Thank you for the response!

Comment: You can access the console as a user, but you need the connection broker to start the console with a ticket (a session password basically) and provide the ticket to you so you can connect. The .vv file contains all that information, so that virt-viewer can start with all the data (ticket, host IP and port), and if you were using Linux or Windows, you could simply install virt-viewer and click the .vv file to open the console. aSpice probably wants the IP, port and ticket fed to it manually

Comment: I already installed the aSpice so the mOvirt will work, but I tried as a user and tried to connect via IP of the machine and port but it didn't work.What do you mean by ticket could you please clarify a bit? Thank you!

Comment: https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/guest-console/connect-to-spice-console-without-portal/